# Asp.Net Identity with 2FA: List of Trusted Browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a project with Asp.Net MVC 5 and Asp.Net Identity and I'm using two factor authentication. For the login I use:

`var result = await SignInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync(model.Provider, model.Code, isPersistent: model.RememberMe, rememberBrowser: model.RememberBrowser);`

which is the default code that came with the new project. However, I also need the ability for a user to "trust" or "remember" a browser, similar to how banks can indicate if this was the first time you have signed in from a particular browser/pc.

My question is around the `RememberBrowser` property on the sign in method and what .NET Identity does with this data.  I want the list of saved browsers and the ability to revoke access to one/and-or all of them. Is that possible within the Identity framework?  Also, can I tell if a browser has been "trusted" before by some type of lookup?

#### Edit:

Maybe it's a good idea to save the browser info in the database and check on login instead of the cookie? That way it can be shown as a list with the ability to delete it. What I'm looking for is what to save and how to integrate it with the Asp.Net Identity without having a security risk.

#### Edit 2

Here's an example from a website that is already using this:
[image: Browser list]

#### Edit 3

Maybe this can be implemented as another step for authentication. So basically we'll have a 3 factor authentication:

- First user logs in with user/pass
- Then we'll check if the 2FA is enabled and get the code if necessary
- We get the user's aser agent and IP and check the database if it's new. Then notify if necessary.

So I'm guessing an new cookie should be added to save browser's info. However, we should be able to invalidate this cookie along with the 2FA cookie.

Comment: I get what you are asking for, but I think you question is a little broad.  If I understand, you want to implement a trusted browser option for your users, much like many banks and other online financial institutions.  If a browser is not trusted, I assume you enforce additional authentication on the user.  Is that about right?

Comment: Exactly. However I assumed that it was built in the Asp.Net Identity. Isn't it? Considering it has a `rememberBrowser` argument

Comment: I can't answer your question, or I would (yay points!).  I just saw your downvote and felt your question has merit but we may want to reword a bit.

Comment: I submitted an edit, please feel free to reject or reword as needed.  I think this focuses your question a little more on the `rememberBrowser` part as well as eludes to asking if Identity has this ability built in.  Good luck, I'm curious to see an answer myself! by the way - i was not the original down voter if that matters

Comment: @Tommy sure. Thanks. Hopefully your edit can help shed some light on what I need and help me get an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether saving browser info adds value as browser info is gonna be same for different users (using same browser and version) unless you save requestor IP as well; and saving requestor IP has too many complications.

How about adding a custom claim to the token if user has set `RememberBrowser` and then do your logic based on this custom claim? For eg, set a custom claim `your_claim_name` and set a `Guid.NewGuid()` to it if `RememberBrowser` is true. Also save the username, this guid and status flag in database . When a request comes, check whether your custom claim is present, if yes query the table with the custom claim value and username to check whether the entry is still active.

You can either delete the entry or soft delete (set the status) the entry for an user so that when next request comes you can perform your required logic.

Comment: I've seen many sites do this. I'm not sure which info they save and how they save it. For instance Google, Microsoft, Facebook. Basically any big company with 2FA login, has an option to "Save Browser". This can be done via cookie for sure but I just wan to 1. Notify the user when a new browser logs in from his account and show the list of the sessions, 2. I want to allow the user to revoke access from one or all of the browsers.

Comment: This is not what I understood from your Q. Not sure whether there is a standard way of doing this. But the above approach could solve your problem. Say you save broser info as well along with the username and guid. You can show the list of active browsers and will be able to give user the ability to log out (basically delete the entry from databse) any active session. RE: big companies, I _think_ they might be using long lived refresh tokens for this purpose

Comment: I've seen this approach on [localbitcoins.com](http://localbitcoins.com). It shows me a list with these info: "Date/User Agent/Location/IP" and then allows me to "Revoke Access" from that browser. Also whenever I login from a new browser, I get an email. I've seen this on other websites too.

Comment: I added a 3rd edit. Maybe it'll help. I sure hope so

Comment: Sure you should be able to do that, but how does adding another cookie solves this? I still think you gotta persist those details in database/any storage so that you could show the list to user and also to check and send email in case he logs in from a different browser.

Comment: Could you provide me a code sample? I'd very much appreciate it

Comment: @AlirezaNoori - I'm not sure whether I'll have the luxury of time this week for this. But let me try explaining it better what I have in my mind (Also please do research whether there are better ways to do this)  1. When Login call is made, check `rememberBrowser` is enabled, if yes, add a custom claim `browser_details' in the token with a Guid value. 2. Save the username, Guid value, user agent info, IP, location and other required properties which you would like to show in the listing into a database table. 3. Repeat the same for all logins.

Comment: 4. So by now, the database table will have all login details to be shown to the user. 5. When "revoke" is clicked, soft/hard delete the corresponding row from that table. 6. Have a custom authorize attribute  which would intrecept all incoming requests and read the custom claim value from token, hit the database to check whether the row for that Guid is still active/present - if that row is inactive, that means the user has revoked access from that browser - handle this scenario as per your business needs (like navigating user to login screen or showing unauthorized page)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. By now I think I now what you mean but I have trouble implementing some of them. I'm afraid I'm gonna introduce some security issues to the website. I'm not in a hurry now. I can get the code in 1 or 2 weeks. Please if possible, provide me with a little code sample. I'll mark your answer as the chosen one and reward you the bounty but please if possible, give me the code. Thanks.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori - Sure, I'll try; I'm kinda screwed up with work now a days, but will try if I could do something.

Answer (score 4):

RememberBrowser sets a cookie that allows the 2FA step to be skipped. There is no central way to track this though it would be easy enough to log, however the results may not be accurate because people can delete cookies manually. There's no way to invalidate it I believe but it doesn't really matter as you can invalidate their session and the user is will be required to login with their password again.

Comment: Thx. Is there a secure way for me to integrate my own method to customize this and save the browsers? I want to achieve the method that other websites such as Microsoft, Google, etc. have implemented.

Comment: Hi, did you have the chance to take a look at this? I'd really appreciate it. Also I have added an edit to my question. Maybe it'll help to clear things out.

Comment: You should have a controller with a login action which calls SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync. This would be the logically place capture browser data